# How to connect two Foreign Key Fields

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have a `model` called `Part` that looks like this:

```
class Part(model.Model) =
    some attributes...
    uses = models.ForeignKey('self', null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, limit_choices_to={'used_in' : None}, related_name = 'part_uses')
    used_in = models.ForeignKey('self', null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, related_name = 'device_used_in')
```

One `Part` can `use` or/and be `used_in` another `Part`, but I need to know which of them it is, to be able to show this in the `DetailView`. In other words, it's not enough to know that there is some kind of relationship between two `Parts`, I need to know which  *kind*  of relationship. (Thus the two different fields).
Now, I want to update `uses` in one object, when another is set to `used_in`, e.g.: if `a.uses(b)` I want to automatically set `b.used_in(a)`.
I did this by setting it manually in the `form_valid` method of my `UpdateView` --> for example, if `a.uses` is changed, look for `b` and change its `used_in`.
For example:

```
if 'used_in' in form.changed_data:  
    if self.object.used_in:
        other_device = Device.objects.filter(pk= self.object.used_in.pk)[0]
        other_device.uses = self.object
        other_device.save()
```

However, this has several disadvantages. First of all, I don't really like having to do this manually and was wondering whether this could not be done some other way, but I didn't find anything on Google. The second problem is that one `Part` can use several other `Parts`, but with my method, only the last `Part` that was `used` is shown.
My question is: Is it somehow possible to connect the two foreign keys inside the model, or shift to only one foreign key, or do this in some other way that makes sense.

Comment: a_uses_b = a.uses(b)   and  b_used_by = b.uses_set

Comment: And if I do this I can differentiate afterwards between uses and is_used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create parent child relation in same table. There is no need to create two field, as `used_in` field is referencing the same object you are updating.

**UPDATE**

Suppose there are 4 objects of Part class.

```
# first part 
>>> part1 = Part.objects.create(name="car engine")
# second part 
>>> part2 = Part.objects.create(name="Spark plug")
# third part 
>>> part3 = Part.objects.create(name="Piston")
# fourth part
>>> part4 = Part.objects.create(name="Piston rings")

# mark part1 uses part2 and part3.
>>> part2.used_in = part1
>>> part2.save()
>>> part3.used_in = part1 
>>> part3.save()

# find parts used in part1.
>>> Part.objects.filter(used_in=part1)

# find part3 is child of which part.
>>> part3.used_in

# mark part3 uses part4
>>> part4.used_in = part3
>>> part4.save()
# this means part1 uses part3 and part3 using part4
```

You can remove `uses` field and make use of just `used_in` field.

Comment: But I still need to differentiate between a `Part` using another or being used, how would I do that?

Comment: Can you explain your usecase, why you need extra field.

Comment: Well, like I explained above, the user should have the option to mark a Part as `uses` or`used_in`, and in the referenced object, the other field should be set. If I don't have two fields, how would I know which Part uses and which Part is used?

Comment: check my update section, i hope this make things clear.

Comment: But the user needs to be able to specify `uses` and/or `used_in` for each of the objects, if I do it like this, only `used_in` would show up in the `UpdateView` wouldn't it? Which means that if he is creating Part3 and he wants to  make it use Part4, he would have to save it first and then go to Part4 and change it there?

Comment: yes this this how it works at database level, You can create custom view and create user interface as per your need write logics accordingly. but correct modeling should be what i explained.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this format :

```
class Parts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(u'Store_Title', max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Partused(models.Model):

    mainpart = models.ForeignKey('Parts', null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, related_name = 'mainpart')
    subpart = models.ForeignKey('Parts', null = True, blank = True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, related_name = 'subpart')    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.mainpart.title + 'uses --> ' + self.subpart.title
```

Search Part :  Parts.objects.get(title = 'Part_to_find')

Search Part Which have subparts :  Partused.objects.filter(mainpart = 'Part_ID')

Search Part Which are subparts to other parts:  Partused.objects.filter(subpart = 'Part_ID')